# Can windows detect when a monitor, mouse, keyboard is disconnected?

Tags: windows, winapi

Can windows detect when a monitor, mouse or keyboard is disconnected from the computer? If so what Win32 API is used for this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the monitor, but the keyboard and mouse being disconnected should fire off a 
WM_DEVICECHANGE message if they are USB devices. See this link for details: [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx)

There is a good discussion of WM_DEVICECHANGE on this [forum](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/32/164968.aspx), relating to its usage with HID devices (Mouse/Keyboard/etc.)

For more detailed notification you can use the RegisterDeviceNotification function
[RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To react to monitor changes, handle WM_DISPLAYCHANGE (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall there is no way to detect PS/2 disconnection events. Monitor and USB can be trapped but I don't know how.

Comment: Well, PS/2 has no disconnection events because it simply doesn't support getting unplugged while in use. And this can fry your controller if you do it :-)